# Troubleshooting Low CPU Utilization in a Multi-threaded Rust Program

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have written a multi-threaded computational Rust program, which launches a number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores to perform a calculation task concurrently. To monitor the parallelism in real time, I used the following method:

```rust
static NUM_THREADS_CAL: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

// ...
// Within the computation thread code
        println!("Current parallelism: {}", NUM_THREADS_CAL.fetch_add(1, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::SeqCst) + 1);
        // The computation part is executed here. This part of the code does not contain IO, locks, or other operations that would block the thread.
        println!("Current parallelism: {}", NUM_THREADS_CAL.fetch_sub(1, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::SeqCst) - 1);
```

The test outputs of `Current parallelism:` are mostly equal to the number of CPU cores or one less. However, the actual CPU usage of the program is only around 15% to 20%. Could you please advise on how I might investigate the possible causes of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way to investigate is to **run a profiler on your program** to tell you where your threads are spending their time. The profiler will show you, at a minimum, which functions your program is spending most of its time in.

(Note that you may need to introduce smaller functions, and maybe even mark some functions `#[inline(never)]`, to get enough information out of those function names!)

---

Secondarily, you should become aware of possible causes of this kind of problem — not necessarily to be able to identify them, but to avoid writing the problematic code in the first place. In general, something specific must be preventing your threads from all running at full CPU speed; if you were doing perfectly pure wasted computation (no communication in or out of the thread) then nothing would stop them from using 100% of a core each.

Most straightforwardly and prototypically, the thread could be blocking, on a system call or acquiring a lock. For example, each of your `println!`s is doing both of those things — hopefully not very often overall, but inserting too much printing *can* severely slow down your program. (If nothing else, if you print so much you overwhelm the terminal's ability to process and display it, your program will have to wait!)

It's also very common for beginners trying to write parallel programs to accidentally use a `std::sync::Mutex` or similar in a way that only one thread can actually make any progress at a time.

And, atomic operations such as your `NUM_THREADS_CAL` require inter-core communication too — much cheaper than a full lock, but still not nothing.

So, one of the key elements of *writing* an efficient parallel program is that you should make sure your work units ("computation parts") are actually big enough that a thread can spend a useful amount of time on one or more of them before it has to do any synchronization at all other threads.

I could say more, but I think that's enough of an overview that you will be able to think about your problem better, and ask a more specific question if the profiler doesn't reveal an obvious problem.